# angular using same pipe for different data

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have search pipe which is working just fine in my `products` page (data) now that I have another set of data `invoices` I would like to use the same pipe in order to search in invoices this time.

#### Question

How do I customize my pipe to accept both `products` and `invoices` depend on page user searching from?

## Code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(products: any[], terms: string): any[] {
    if (!products) { return []; }
    if (!terms) { return products; }
    terms = terms.toLowerCase();
    return products.filter( it => {
      return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(terms);
    });
  }

}
```

> PS: I have [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49007257/angular5-use-same-pipe-for-two-level-array-data) but I couldn't understand it exactly.

## Update

Based on answers below here is how invoices data look like,

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "user_id":1,
        "name":"cargo website",
        "quantity":"1",
        "body":"frhsaeh",
        "terms":"aehyaejhu",
        "employee":"xyz company",
        "employer":"mr. xyz",
        "price":"5000000.00",
        "dp":"2500000.00",
        "remained":"2500000.00",
        "tax":"10.00",
        "start":"2019-10-28T00:00:00.000000Z",
        "ends":"2019-12-26T00:00:00.000000Z",
        "status":"on hold",
        "tracks":[
            {
                "id":2,
                "user_id":1,
                "invoice_id":1,
                "image":"http:\/\/.....test\/images",
                "body":"this is second one."
            }
        ],
        "created_at":"2019-10-27 09:43:14",
        "updated_at":"2019-10-27 09:43:14"
    }
]
```

## Update 2

This is how my search bar look like.

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="terms" placeholder="{{ 'SEARCH.find_invoice' | translate }}"></ion-searchbar>
```

## Update 3

In both controllers i have this,

```
descending = false;
order: number;
column = 'name';
terms = '';

sort() {
  this.descending = !this.descending;
  this.order = this.descending ? 1 : -1;
}
```

And in both views `products`, `invoices` I have this,

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col size="8" offset="2">
        <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="terms" placeholder="{{ 'SEARCH.find_invoice' | translate }}"></ion-searchbar>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>

<div *ngIf="terms else Items">

    <ion-button float-right fill="outline" size="default" type="button" (click)="sort()">
        <ion-icon name="funnel"></ion-icon>
        {{ 'SEARCH.sort' | translate }}
    </ion-button>

    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let p of invoices | search : terms | sort: {property: column, order: order}" routerDirection="forward" [routerLink]="['/', 'tracks', p.user_id, p.id]">

            <!-- show items details -->
            <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
                <ion-img [src]="p.image"></ion-img>
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <ion-label>{{ p.name }}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>

<ng-template #Items>
    show ordinary list when user not searching
</ng-template>
```

Note: the only difference between my `products` and `invoices` search list is this line `*ngFor="let p of invoices | ....` `*ngFor="let p of products | ....`

Comment: Which field in the `invoices` object are you matching against?

Comment: @christian `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple modification so that you can pass which *field to be searched* for.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'search'
})

@Injectable()
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
        if (!items) {
            return [];
        }
        if (!field || !value) {
            return items;
        }
        return items.filter(singleItem => singleItem[field].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
    }
}
```

For searching products,

```
*ngFor="let product of products | search : 'name' : searchText"
```

If you want to search invoices by id,

```
*ngFor="let invoice of invoices | search : 'id' : searchText"
```

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szzvxw

Comment: This is basically return all the data of `products` and `invoices` regarding to what page i'm searching for **regardless** of what I'm typing! is just like loading all products in products page and load all invoices in invoices page.

Comment: i can provide video screen if you need

Comment: Initially it will load the whole list. Once you start typing, the pipe uses the input to return only the matching ones.

Comment: please check this screen video to see what i'm getting https://www.loom.com/share/bcc8b8bbca7a4113bfa14938dee4185d

Comment: There is something wrong in your implementation. Please provide the code where you are using the pipes i.e. both products and invoices page code snippet

Comment: @mafortis I have provided a demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szzvxw). Check that and see where you have made it wrong.

Comment: @mafortis I see where you got it wrong. You have to pass the field to be searched for i.e. `search : 'name' : terms`

Comment: yep that was it :). Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If you're searching against the `name` field for both `products` and `invoices`, then you should be able to use the pipe for both as is (might just want to rename variables so it's not only `products`).

If you're searching against different fields for different collections, then you can make the pipe more generic. You can update the pipe to pass the additional arg as an object of a search field and search term.

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  // EXAMPLE "let product of products | search: { searchTerm, searchField }"
  transform(collection: any[], searchConfig: { searchTerm: string; searchField: string }): any[] {
    if (!collection) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!searchConfig.searchTerm || !searchConfig.searchField) {
      return collection;
    }
    return collection.filter(it => {
      return it[searchConfig.searchField]
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchConfig.searchField.toLowerCase());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: is `searchField` same as my `terms`? because i don't want to change names and later be forced to edit controllers as well.

Comment: This is basically return all the data of `products` and `invoices` regarding to what page i'm searching for **regardless** of what I'm typing! is just like loading all products in products page and load all invoices in invoices page.

Comment: i can provide video screen if you need